# Month display in English but required in Swedish?

Tags: date, post-formats

I am using WordPress settings like below Image:

[image]

On post output come like **13 October 11:49** but my requirement is to make it like **oktober** in Swedish and same for all other months.

Thanks!

Comment: What language is WordPress set to?

Comment: Site Language is set to English, do I need to change that ?

Comment: Probably, because that is what WordPress is probably using. In PHP you can change it by using the setlocale() function but that would probably require a deeper dive than just simply flipping the language in WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to select *Svenska* here:

[image: svenska]

just beneath the *Date Format* settings.